# Form button won't move to new entry when saved

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form for entering data records into a Table.

[Form Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SCmK.png)

When I open the form (which I have set with ‘DataEntry = Yes’) it correctly opens as a blank form ready to add a new record as I want.

When the Add Record button is clicked it correctly saves the record to the Table and clears all fields using the code at the bottom.

So once Add Record is clicked it would appear that the form is ready to enter data into a new record (as it is now blank) but when I enter data into the now blank form and click Add Record again, it saves the new data over the record just entered (i.e. it overwrites it) so it’s always writing to the same record in the Table. It will only write to a new record if the form is closed and opened again.

Could you please let me know what to change so when the Add Record button is clicked it saves the record to the table, clears the Form and instead when clicked again it adds a **New** record to the Table.

Many Thanks

[Code Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZE1i.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all code for `BeforeUpdate` and replace all code for Add_Record by

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

Data in current record will be saved automatically as soon as you change the record or move focus out from the subform with data